# Use external configuration in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration

Is there some library or tool to allow a rails application to be configured using external files?

I want the database configuration (by default in `config/database.yml`) and the application configuration (configured in a environment specific file in `config/environments/*.rb`) to be in files (preferably yaml) *not included* in the project.

I know that this is not the standard way of doing things, but has some benefits:

- The files can live in separate repository in version control
- You can have different access control to this repository (you can hide the production configuration)
- The config files can be deployed separately
- You can change them manually on the machine, and they won't be overwritten when the application is re-deployed
- You don't have to have a different rails environment for each deployment environment, but can have the changes made on that specific machine.
- You could share configurations between applications

An even better solution would be to have partial external configuration - this way you can still have your basic configuration in the application, but overwrite parts of it.

It's is possible to do if you copy the external config files inside the application. This can be done in the beginning of `config/application.rb` before rails is loaded, but it looks like a hack, and hard to maintain. Is there some practical solution to allow this?

Comment: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Configuration_Management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dotenv is excellent and does exactly what you want.  It's very common and a great way to keep secrets out of shared files. Combine it with env_bang-rails for some added goodness (defaults, failures if undefined, etc.)

https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv

https://github.com/jcamenisch/ENV_BANG/